# For loop not changing value

Tags: php

I need to subtract 10 from a value until it's below ten and then use it outside of the loop but the value doesn't seem to change.
I'm not sure how many wrongs I'm making but I bet it's many!

```
$x = 1987;
$y = 2015;
$b = $y - $x;
for($b; $b > 10; $b - 10){
    echo $b; //This is supposed to be echo:ed when the loop is done
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not actually modifying `$b`:

```
$x = 1987;
$y = 2015;
$b = $y - $x;
for($b; $b > 10; $b = $b - 10) { // <- this line
    echo $b;
}
```

Also, there is no need for the initial `$b` here:

```
for(; $b > 10; $b = $b - 10) {
```

Or you could get rid of:

```
$b = $y - $x;
```

And just use:

```
for($b = $y - $x; $b > 10; $b = $b - 10) {
```

Comment: You can shorten that to `$b -= 10`

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just do

```
$x = 1987;
$y = 2015;
$b = ($y - $x) % 10;
```

Which is basically what you're doing, only you chose the hard way with the `for` loop :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = 1987;
$y = 2015;
$b = $y - $x;
for(; $b > 10; $b -= 10);
echo $b;
```

echo will happen only after completing loop. This will reduce the `$b` value by multiples of 10. `$b` will be `less than 10` after loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$x = 1987;
$y = 2015;
$b = $y - $x;
for($b; $b > 10; $b -= 10) { 
    echo $b; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A while loop is more readable than a for loop. Also, put the echo statement after the loop has completed.

```
$x = 1987;
$y = 2015;
$b = $y - $x;
while($b > 10) {
    $b -= 10;
}
echo $b;
```